# Changing base does not affect the ratio of logarithms and links back to base 10

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

We know that $\log 2 = 0.301$
If we change to a different base e.g. $2$ we have:
$\log_2 2 = 1$
$\log_2 10 = 3.3219$
and $\frac{\log_2 2}{\log_2 10} = 0.301$

If we change to base $1.4$ we have:
$\log_{1.4} 10 = 6.8433$
$\log_{1.4} 2 = 2.0600$
and $\frac{\log_{1.4} 2}{\log_{1.4} 10} = 0.301$

So we keep getting approximately the $\log_{10} 2$ from the ratio of the other bases.

My question is what is the underlying idea/principle behind this? I am not interested in a "name" of an existing formula but the intuition and principle behind it.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have mentioned the change of base formula, but where does it come from?

Saying that $\log_b(x)=y$ is the same thing as saying $b^y=x$.  Taking $\log_c$ of both sides yields, $\log_c(b^y)=\log_c(x)$.  Using the exponent properties of logs, $y\log_c(b)=\log_c(x)$, so $y=\log_c(x)/\log_c(b)$.  Recalling the definition of $y$, we have our final formula

$$\log_b(x)=\frac{\log_c(x)}{\log_c(b)}.$$

So we see that the change of base formula is a consequence of the definition of log, and the exponent property of logs.

Comment: This helps and is very clear. I was wondering how does one usually "discover" such properties to begin with? In this specific case is there some underlying principle/intuition that one had about the topic and the confirms it by direct application of the definitions?

Comment: It is much harder to discover what is true than to figure out why something is true.  There are a number of ways to hit upon a possible truth.  It might be a generalization or analogue of something else you know to be true, you might have examples that suggest it, it might be something you would like to be true in order to explain something else you believe, or you might just be playing around and stumble upon it accidentally.  But once you know what you want to show, there are often only a handful of different things to try which seem promising, and you can try many of them.

Comment: I was wondering in this specific case i.e. for the logarithm, do you think the train of thought started by understanding some underlying principle that prompted to the verification of the application of definitions?

Comment: It personally seems like a natural thing to come up with if you wanted to have something with two different types of logs, but that is just me.

Comment: Thinking this more, I get the impression that the idea is that of simple change of scale. E.g. if base is $1.1$ we need between $7$ and $8$ multiplications to get to $2$ and between $24$ and $25$ multiplications to get to $10$. Since the approx $24.5$ multiplications in base $1.1$ correspond to $1$ in base $10$ then the approx $7.4$ multiplications for $2$ correspond to $\frac{7.4}{24.5} = 0.302$ which is approximately $log_{10} 2$. I am not sure if what I say is formally correct, does it make sense?

Comment: It might be easier to think about if you use even numbers.  If you use base 2, it takes 4 multiplications to make 16 and 8 multiplications to make 256.  If you use base 4, it takes 2 multiplications to make 16 and 4 multiplications to make 256.  In fact, with even numbers, you can see the change of base formula as coming from $(b^m)^n=b^{mn}$.

Comment: This is the basic formula of logarithm.  Most likely, there are 10s of copies on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is a bit vague, are you referring to the change of base property for logarithms?

$$log_b(a)= \frac{log_z(a)}{log_z(b)}$$ where z is any number for which the logs are defined.
[image: Change of base property]

Comment: That is the formula yes. I am asking what is the idea behind this formula and underlying principle

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\log_{1.4}2}{\log_{1.4}10} = \frac{\log_{1.4}10^{\log_{10}2}}{\log_{1.4}10}=\frac{\log_{10}2\cdot\log_{1.4}10}{\log_{1.4}10}=\log_{10}2$$

What if you choose a different base? Can you generalize this idea?